# How does one parse 'woe betide'?

Tags: meaning, subjunctive-mood, conjugation, imperatives, verb-forms

How would one parse the sentence

> Woe betide anyone wearing the wrong colour! ?

*Betide* is clearly the main verb, meaning *happen*;  as in *they waited wondering what might betide.*

But clearly *betide* is not conjugated like other verbs, otherwise it would be *woe betides.* But in this usage of *woe betide...*, it doesn't even seem to me to be acting like an indicative verb. It is most frequently delivered as an imperative warning, a bit like *look out.*

Should the full form be *Woe will betide anyone....?*

Comment: It's subjunctive. Since this is the only place that we use *betide* anymore, we never see *betide* conjugated properly.

Comment: *Betide* doesn't mean *happen*. It means "fall upon", or "**happen to**" and it must take an object.

Comment: What @Peter said. I think it's General Reference that the "fixed expression" **woe betide** is in the subjunctive, so there's really nothing much left to say. Except that some other usages of **betide** (all of which I'd call obsolete, archaic, or dated) are (or were) intransitive, so it doesn't *always* need to take an object.

Comment: @Andrew: according to the OED, *betide* meant either *happen* or *happen to*. From the OED (both from 2nd half of 18th century): *Betide, betide, whate'er betide, Haig shall be Haig of Bemerside* and *The death of my son betiding while my soul was under this anxiety.* Of course, today both of these meanings are essentially archaic.

Comment: @PeterShor Is there not a case for saying that 'Woe betide...' is a composite with an idiomatic meaning in its own right?   'Betide' to my mind seems to be saying 'awaits'. 'Woe betide (awaits) anyone  who is ill prepared'

Comment: Nothing in the subjunctive is "general reference". Since there is no subjunctive in English, but rather a disorganized bunch of idioms and fixed phrases, general reference contains no useful information about it. The phrase _woe betide `X`_ is short for _May woe betide `X`_; _betide_ is an infinitive, just like any verb following a modal. And it's a fixed phrase, which means it's irregular. *That* part is common knowledge, anyway.

Comment: Any curse can be modified by a hypothetical clause; this puts conditions on the curse. _God damn you to hell if you touch a hair of his head_ is a conditional curse, with exactly the same structure as _Woe betide you if you ..._.

Comment: @PeterShor Please phrase your response in the form of an answer.

Comment: I agree and appreciate this sharp and stark utterance; let this live forever. This resonates as a stylish poetic, lyrical and Shakespearean dramatic expression used as a direct wake-up call.

Comment: @JohnLawler, I'm confused about there not being a subjunctive in English. If there were no subjunctive, how could I say "I recommended that he look it up in the dictionary?" (Or if that isn't a subjunctive, what is it?) Not trying to be argumentative; just not clear on why you're saying there's no subjunctive.

Answer (score 6):

In the phrase, *"woe betide"*, the verb *"betide"* is in the subjunctive mood. This is one of the left-over uses of the present subjunctive in fixed phrases. It means *"may woe betide"*, like *"long live the king"* means *"may the king live long"*.

According to the OED, *betide* meant *happen* or *happen to*. It was a regular verb conjugated like other verbs. However, nowadays the only place we see it used is in the expression *woe betide*.

Comment: John Lawler's comment above is of interest too. I am also conscious that there are two senses in which woe betide is used. 1. May woe betide him if he harms anyone i.e. as a threat. and 2. Woe betide you if you break the law - i.e as a warning. It is a bit like *Heaven help him...* Indeed that phrase can be substituted for *woe betide him* in each of these two examples.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, the conjugation (as per my ancient school days) of the sentence "Woe betide you" is as follows: "Woe" is the noun, "betide" is the verb, and "you" is the object of the verb.

Comment: The most important thing is lacking, that the verb form betide (without -s) is present subjunctive. And, of course, the meaning of the old words should be explained.