# Must "may" be in subjective verbs?

Tags: subjunctive-mood

For example:

> God bless America.

seems to be a shorter way of saying

> May God bless America.

Is "bless" in both of these cases in the subjunctive?

("God, bless America." is clearly imperative.)

Comment: Related: http://english.stackexchange.com/a/358225, http://english.stackexchange.com/q/189171

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Subjunctive" refers to a set of endings for verbs in various languages. It is nearly obsolete in English, but

> God bless America.

is one of the surviving examples. "Bless" is subjunctive there.

> May God bless America.

has very similar meaning, and has replaced that use of the subjunctive except in a few set expressions (for example "God bless... ", "Long live ... "). It uses the modal auxiliary "may" followed by the infinitive (basic form) of the verb "bless".

The infinitive is identical to the old subjunctive in every case, even the wildly irregular verb "be"; but it is preferable to treat this construction as using the infinitive because all other uses of modal auxiliaries (eg 'must', 'can' could', should') take the infinitive. I've never come across an account suggesting that "bless" is the subjunctive form of the verb when it is in "may ... bless".

Some people do refer to this *construction* as "subjunctive", but I've never seen any point in doing so: in most languages, "subjunctive" refers to a set of verb forms.

Comment: «_I've never come across an account suggesting that "bless" is the subjunctive form of the verb when it is in "may ... bless"_» So grammatically "may" is no different than "can"?

Comment: Syntactically, _may_ is no different from _can_, or for that matter from _will_ (which is why I maintain that English has no future tense). Semantically, of course, it is different; and that has one very odd consequence: this form "May X <do> Y" (as in this example) is not necessarily a question, whereas with any other modal it would be a question.